# What could be the source of this noise?

Tags: noise, fft

Below is the output of an accelerometer when it is standing still:

[image]

The zoomed 0.5 seconds of time series voltage data above is from a 4 seconds of measurement with a data acquisition board at 30kHz sampling rate. I also observed the same waveform with a scope.

And here below is the FFT of the signal:

[image]

As you at the FFT plot there are peaks at 100Hz, 200Hz, 300Hz, 400Hz, 500Hz, 600hz so forth and so on.

I have been told that the shield of the cable(CAT6) is either floating or wired to mains earth or wired to the DC ground of the SMPS power supply inside the enclosure. I dont know which one is set now.

But before I go and examine it, I'm wonderin what can be said about nature of such noise.

If it was 50Hz noise I thought I would see only 50Hz dominating. But now both even and odd harmonics of 50Hz appears at FFT. Can this be related to 50Hz coupling or SMPS switching noise?

Comment: Is there a light source nearby which is controlled by a dimmer? Phase switching for such a device will occur on both phases of AC, producing 100 Hz, and the fast rise times would generate the harmonics. Alternatively, fluorescent bulbs do the same thing.

Comment: No not anything with dimmer, but inside the box there are 10 tiny dual supply SMPSs. I could provide more data but I dont have access at the monet to the board.

Comment: Is this a accelerometer with a charge amp? Is the room vibrating?

Comment: No it is servo https://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-107ln.pdf Room is not vibrating I use CAT6 cable for the power and signals, this noise is Im suspecting is about shield's coupling. But Im not sure if it is related to SMPS or some other source.

Comment: at 100Hz it could be from the input rectifiers  in those power supplies.